# Delaying events until a callback is called (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Node.js with Express and have code similar to this as part of my routes:

```
requireLogin: function(req, res, next) {
    User.find(req.session.userId)
        .on('success', function(user) {
             req.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
                 console.log("DATA: " + chunk);
             }
             next()
        }
}
```

I am using Sequelize and the User.find method is accessing the database. The trouble is, the request 'data' event that I bind to is never fired. It seems that the data event had already been triggered and handled by the time the user is returned from the database and it's too late to do anything with it. In the example above I could just move the req.addListener to outside the database callback, but in reality I am calling next() here which can't be moved.

All of the following route middleware that is called by next() then doesn't have access to the request data since these events have already been fired. Worse than that, they just hang waiting for the data event from req because it has already happened.

How can I somehow delay the data event so that it can be bound to from within the database callback? Or have I misunderstood something fundamental and need to change my way of going about this?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: I found a [relevant discussion in the nodejs Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/6e7bc2508abd1717#) which suggests there isn't a solution that will work for me.

Comment: explain why you can't move the `req` up the chain. Give a more concrete example.

Comment: @Raynos: I have added in the 'next()' function call which is actually where the problem lies in my real code. I have also expanded on this in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cache = new function () {
    var arr = [],
        cbs = [];

    this.add = function(data) {
        arr.push(data);
        cbs.forEach(function(cb) {
            cb(arr);
        });
    }

    this.get = function(cb) {
        cbs.push(arr);
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            cb(arr);
        }
    }
};

req.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    cache.add(chunk);
};

User.find(
    req.session.userId
).on('success', function(user) {
    cache.get(function(data) {
        // stuff
        next();
    });

};
```

I presume what you actually want is some kind of message caching. Now this is a vague proof of concept. What you actually want depends on your code.

If you have any kind of deferred library / abstraction available then the code will become a lot smaller.

Comment: Thanks, that would work in some cases but I can't use a cache like this because the next() function calls code which uses an external library which binds to the 'data' event directly. It looks like this is an issue which is currently without a good solution: [Google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/6e7bc2508abd1717#)

Comment: @JamesAllen Your problem is binding to the data event after data is submitted down it.